# Google Chrome Translate Page Does Not Work

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, google-translate

In Google Chrome, **Translate to English** (*or any other language*) function was working fine, but all of the sudden it stopped working.

By looking at the console, I see error messages when the page tries to translate:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/t?anno=3&client=te_lib&format=html&v=1.0&key=no&logld=vTE_20170619_02&sl=da&tl=en&tc=1&tk=927511.556110&mode=1
```

I tried completely uninstalling **Google Chrome** and installing it again but it still does not work, it also does not work in **Incognito Window**.

It works fine in other machines, any ideas?

Comment: At a quick glance: if you are accessing Google Translate through work or school, I could see them blocking it so it couldn't be used to bypass their filters.

Comment: @llvmastproject that is actually very possible, I'm accessing it through work network, is there a way to test if it is the issue or not? and if so, is there a way to get around it?

Comment: @llvmastproject I tried it from a colleague's computer which is connected to the same network and it worked fine! We also have almost the same machine, any idea?

Comment: Try it on another work machine that goes through the work network, and if you still have the same problem but not on like a home computer, then that's probably it. I would not recommend trying to get around it. I would just say access Google Translate on a non-work device, or tell your work why you want to access Google Translate -- they might let you through.

Comment: @llvmastproject I just did, it works fine on a colleague's computer which is connected to the same network :/

Comment: Sorry, I just read your new comment, can you tell me what you are doing on your machine when you get the error? What happens if you search something like "translate vase to spanish" in google? Does the "in-search" google translate work?

Comment: @llvmastproject yes I tried that and "in-search" worked fine, Google Translate also works fine, but when I right-click in the page and click Translate to English, it does not translate (it used to until a few days ago), looking at the Console, I found the error messages in the question.

Comment: And it is still happening? Even after a browser restart?

Comment: Yes, and even after complete re-installation :/

Comment: What happens if you go the long way and go to https://translate.google.com/ , and paste in an address (like https://stackoverflow.com )

Comment: It works fine if I go through Google Translate :)

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you have an extension that could be messing with the right click method? Do you let your extensions work even in Incognito?

Comment: I did try that, I disabled all the extensions, and used Incognito, but didn't solve it :/

Comment: Did you make sure that Chrome deleted everything when you reinstalled it?

Comment: Yes! From The AppData folders and everywhere :/

Comment: I've had Google Chrome silently update on me before, so that might be why it was working differently a couple days ago. What is your OS? It might be helpful to try to downgrade chrome to see if that's an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148893/discussion-between-llvmastproject-and-mohammad-anini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you don't have the api key:

```
key=no
```

Look at environment variables to see if `GOOGLE_API_KEY` is set to `no` and delete it.

Comment: Thank you, but where can find the environment variables?

Comment: What's your OS? Linux: open terminal and type `env`. Windows: open command prompt and type `set`.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I would just translate pages the long way.

I.E.:

Going to https://translate.google.com and typing your address in the input box, and going to address produced in the output box.

---

If you want to continue our discussion from the comments, I have created a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148893/discussion-between-llvmastproject-and-mohammad-anini) for us to keep talking about your issue.